# Does geth removed whisper(--shh)?

Tags: whisper

Here (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) I can see that `--shh` flag exists, under `geth  v1.9.19-stable-3e064192`

```
WHISPER (EXPERIMENTAL) OPTIONS:
  --shh                               Enable Whisper
```

---

But on the `geth v1.10.1-stable-c2d2f4ed` ; `--shh` does not exist, is it completely removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whisper-related flags were removed in Geth v1.10.0 (see the release notes, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.0)) in issue [#22421](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/22421).

However, Whisper itself was removed earlier, in v1.9.21 (release notes, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.9.21)).